# Buffer stream from microphone iterating results

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, naudio

What i would like to do is, constantly listen the microphone, have the microphone writer that writes into a stream, when the stream has x lenght, yield result, clear the stream and keep doing it it in a loop.
Then from the caller analyse all bytes received, i am a bit new to microphone recording, i don't event know if the code below register something, I am using NAudio library:

this is the caller:

```
var buffers = service.StreamHearing();
foreach (var buffer in buffers)
{
    //analyse
}
```

and then is the actual service:

```
public IEnumerable<byte[]> StreamHearing()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[512];
        using(var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        using(var writer = new WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(stream), new WaveFormat(44100, 1)))
        {
            var recorder = new WaveInEvent
            {
                WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1),
                BufferMilliseconds = 100
            };

            recorder.StartRecording();
            while (true)
            {
                yield return buffer;
                buffer = new byte[512];
                stream.SetLength(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

this doesn't work, please give me a hand on how to do it.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand a couple of things which you miss.
First of all, `WaveInEvent` will write the data from the microphone asynchronously. Here is a correct snippet for writing the data from the microphone to some stream:

```
var buffer = new byte[512];
var recorder = new WaveInEvent
{
   WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1),
   BufferMilliseconds = 100
};
var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
var writer = new WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(stream), recorder.WaveFormat);
recorder.DataAvailable += (source, eventArgs) => 
{
    var data = eventArgs.Buffer;
    var bytesRead = eventArgs.BytesRecorded;
    //here is a place where data from the microphone will be available
    //you can add your processing right here in case you don't need to record and save the data
    writer.Write(data, 0, bytesRead);
};

waveIn.StartRecording();
```

There are multiple different ways on how to proceed with the data you receive, but I don't know your main goal, so it is hard to say what is better way you choose the processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see what you mean, i was completely missing that bit. What i would like to do is, never stop the recording, and by x interval send the data to do some processing, so this will act kind of like a background job that input data to in some method.